# In java, is there a way to convert a control character to a set of characters in a string?

Tags: java, char

Sorry if the title was poorly phrased, but I am trying to make a program that can find a way of detecting whether each individual character in a string is a control character or not. If there is a control character, it should replace that control character with a set of characters. For example, the String "an/0Example" should become "anotherExample", assuming that "other" is what I want to replace with the control character. The code I have so far is below, but my understanding is that a character, with the exception of a control character, cannot contain more than one character.

```
    int i = 0;
    char exampleCh = identifier.charAt(i);
    
    for(i = 0; i < identifier.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isISOControl(example)){
            identifier = identifier.replace(exampleCh, 'exampleReplacement');
        }
     }
```

Comment: Do you want to create custom control characters? or do you just want to replace existing ones? you question is not clear.

Comment: Did you mean `\0`?

Comment: "a character, with the exception of a control character, cannot contain more than one character" -- this is meaningless.  A character does not 'contain' characters, it **is** a character. One character. Regardless of whether it's a control character.

Comment: Oh, maybe I get it.  You're confused because a single character (like 'newline') is representable **in Java source code** by the sequence backslash, letter-n.  It's still one 16-bit char in the string.  This is just a notational convenience for non-printing characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have to following input string:

```
String str = "an\0Example";
```

We can replace the control character using conventional loop and a string builder:

```
String replacement = "another";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    stringBuilder.append(Character.isISOControl(c) ? replacement : c);
}
String result = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Or we can use streams:

```
String result = str.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> Character.isISOControl(c) ? replacement : String.valueOf((char)c))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Please note, according to [`isISOControl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl-char-) method, this `an/0Example` does not contain any kind of control character. Instead of `/0`, I believe you would wanted to have this `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

## Escapes processed by compiler

The escapes embedded in a string literal are processed by the compiler, and transformed as the intended character. So at runtime, the string object contains a null, and does *not* contain a backslash and zero seen in your literal `"an\0Example"`.

You can see this in the following code.

```
    String input = "an\0Example" ;
    System.out.println(
        Arrays.toString(
            input.codePoints().toArray()
        )
    );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/m1DrN2). Notice the zero in third position, a null character, followed by the seven characters of the word “Example”.

> [97, 110, 0, 69, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101]

## Avoid `char`

Never use `char` type. That type has been legacy as of Java 2, essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

## Code points

Use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
for( int codePoint : input.codePoints().toArray() ){
    if( ! Character.isISOControl( codePoint ) ) {
        sb.appendCodePoint( codePoint ) ;
    }
 }
String output = sb.toString() ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( output ) ;
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( output.codePoints().toArray() ) ) ;
}
System.out.println( output.codePoints().mapToObj( Character :: toString ).toList() ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/m1DrN2).

> anExample
>
> [97, 110, 69, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101]
>
> [a, n, E, x, a, m, p, l, e]

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can test the relevant control characters. For example, to make the control characters visible:

```
public static String rawString(String s)
{ String res = ""; 
  if (s == null) 
  { return res; } 

  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
  { char c = s.charAt(i); 
    if (c == '\b')
    { res = res + '\\' + 'b'; } 
    else if (c == '\n')
    { res = res + '\\' + 'n'; } 
    else if (c == '\t')
    { res = res + '\\' + 't'; }
    else if (c == '\r')
    { res = res + '\\' + 'r'; } 
    else if (c == '\f')
    { res = res + '\\' + 'n'; }
    else if (c == '\\')
    { res = res + '\\' + '\\'; }
    else if (c == '\'')
    { res = res + '\\' + '\''; } 
    else if (c == '\"')
    { res = res + '\\' + '\"'; } 
    else if (c == '\0')
    { res = res + '\\' + '0'; } 
    else if (c == '\1')
    { res = res + '\\' + '1'; } 
    else if (c == '\2')
    { res = res + '\\' + '2'; } 
    else if (c == '\3')
    { res = res + '\\' + '3'; } 
    else if (c == '\4')
    { res = res + '\\' + '4'; } 
    else if (c == '\5')
    { res = res + '\\' + '5'; } 
    else if (c == '\6')
    { res = res + '\\' + '6'; } 
    else if (c == '\7')
    { res = res + '\\' + '7'; } 
    else 
    { res = res + c; } 
  } 
  return res; 
}
```